# How can check null value in nullable type in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I check null value for a nullable type?

This is my code

```
public int? ContractYear
{
    get
    {
        if (Dates.FindIndex((Date d) => d.Type == DateType.Issue) == -1)
            return null;

        return DateTime.Now.Year - 
               Dates.First((Date d) => d.Type == DateType.Issue).Year.Value;
    }
}
```

In the above code, `Date` is a custom type with a Year property within my code and `Dates` is a collection of `Date` objections.  Here is how they are defined:

```
public List<Date> Dates // initialized elsewhere

public class Date
{
    public DateType Type { get; set; }  //DateType is an enum
    public int? Year { get; set; }       
    //additional properties
}
```

In line `.Year.Value` I am getting the error because if year could be `null` then we can not get the value of year and it will throw "Nullable object must have a value"

Now how can I put the check for this error.

Comment: please add it in my code..

Comment: Don't add excess info, like "please don't give me downvote".  That is only going to attract more downvotes.  Instead try to figure out what is wrong with your question.  It is completely unanswerable because you haven't given us enough info.  We're not looking at your code, so how in the world are we supposed to know what `Date` and `Dates` are?  `Date` is obviously a custom type in your project, and `Dates` looks like it could be a collection of `Date` objects, but I'm just guessing

Comment: actually i am new user in stack overflow so there could be some mistakes..  but it does not mean that u have to vote it down.Because of it, in future i can not add more questions

Comment: What are `Date` and `Dates`?  You never answered that question?

Comment: Dates is a collection list<Date> and Date is custom type

Comment: I figured that much out per my original comment, but I'm not looking at your screen, so I can't see the class.  How is `Date` defined?  What are its properties and their types?  Specifically what type is Date.Year?  Is it an `int` or something else?

Comment: Or is `Date.Year` a nullable int?

Comment: yes Date.Year is nullable int

Comment: A piece of advise for you in asking questions, these are the kind of details you need to include in your question.  And the fact that they were missing could be very well why your question was downvoted.  Someone who wants to answer your question needs to be able to run your code and reproduce the problem, and they can't do that when you have unexplained types in the sample.

Comment: Thnx for advice. i will really keep these things in mind in future.

Comment: @psubsee2003 : Hi, Now i can see the difference between my post and updated post. Really Thnx for guiding me and and also for rectifying my errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44393/discussion-between-shruti-singh-and-psubsee2003)

Comment: I don't really have time to go to chat, it's 5am here and I'm just getting my morning started.  If you have specific questions about my answer, feel free to comment under the answer and I will try to respond when I have a chance.

Comment: Actually i was trying to move this conversation in to chat.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check for value using yournullableType.[HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) to check if it hasvalue or not

> Each instance of a nullable type has two public read-only properties:
>   **HasValue**
>   HasValue is of type bool. It is set to true when the variable contains a non-null value.
>   **Value**
>   Value is of the same type as the underlying type. If HasValue is true, Value contains a meaningful value. If HasValue is false, accessing Value will throw a InvalidOperationException.

Like

```
int? x = 10;
if (x.HasValue)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Undefined");
}
```

Comment: give a working example and you will get a working answer

Comment: @ShrutiSingh are you kidding? You asked how to check for null and you were told. Job done.

Comment: @Gusdor :not getting, what do u want to say

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you are getting the error when `Year` is null.  When working with nullable types, calling the `Value` property when the value is null will throw an exception.

To avoid this, you need to make use of the `HasValue` property and check it before calling `Value`.  However, you need to decide how you want to handle this specific problem, specifically what do you want to do when Year is null?

```
public int? ContractYear
{
    get
    {
        var firstIssueDate = Dates.FirstOrDefault((Date d) => d.Type == DateType.Issue);


        if (firstIssueDate == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (firstIssueDate.Year.HasValue)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Year - firstIssueDate .Year.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return ??? 
            //this is what you need to decide, 
            // what do you want to return when Year is null?
        }
    }
}
```

There are other alternatives on how to handle the case when `Year` is null, depending on what you want to return when that happens.  Another very common pattern is the conditional operator (`?:`)

```
return DateTime.Now.Year - 
       firstIssueDate.Year.HasValue ? firstIssueDate.Year.Value : 0; 
// you can replace the 0 above with whatever 
// value you want to use in lieu of a null Year.
```

Comment: I revised the code slightly in my answer so you only have to do the query once.  This is a better practice and should theoretically run a little faster (but unless `Dates` is large, you probably won't notice a speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value.

```
static void Main()
    {
        int? num = null;

        // Is the HasValue property true? 
        if (num.HasValue)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
        }
```